# CSS inheritance -- color property

Tags: css, colors, css-specificity

Probably missing something really simple here as I am quite new to this -- but, I don't understand why, in the below code, the `<a>` and `<h2>` elements do not inherit the `color` property (white) from the `.hero` class. Simplified the code as much as possible.

The HTML:

```
<section class="hero container">
    <h2>A header!</h2>
    <p>Some stuff!!!</p>
    <a href="something.html">Linky</a>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
a {
    color: #648880;
}

h2 {
    color: #648880;
}

.hero {
    color: #fff;
}
```

The result of this code is that the `<p>` element has text w/ color `#fff`, as specified in the `.hero` class -- which is as expected. However, the `<a>` & `<h2>` elements have color `#6488880`, as specified in the element selectors for `<a>` & `<p>`.

Same issue demonstrated in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxbupfc/)

Shouldn't the `.hero` class's `color` attribute be overriding the `color` attribute in the element selectors? Am I completely misunderstanding specificity somehow? Of course I can use `.hero a` or `.hero h2`, but I don't see why I have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you expect a property specified on a parent to override one specified on a child?

Specificity refers to a way to prioritize rules **selecting the same element**. The specificity of a rule on a parent (`.hero`) has no relevance to the specificity of a rule on its children (`a`).

In this case, the default `color` on the `a` element is `inherit`. However, you explicitly specified a different color. No amount of specificity or `!important` on the parent can cause it to override an explicit color specified on the child.

Answer (score 0):

You set the elements to a specific color. Setting the color of the parent won't override that. You need to be more specific about those elements.

```
.hero a, 
.hero h2{
    color: inherit;
}
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) may help.

Comment: try to avoid being more specific if possible, getting more and more specific causes problems

Comment: Not in this instance though.